# Why Jlist is selecting index 0 even when the item is not present there

Tags: java, swing, jlist, selectionmodel

Why Jlist is selecting index 0 even when the item is not present there.

Here is my code I have created a JList lst and set its content as a vector vct which consists of objects of class people which when invoked toString() provides with details of people.Which look like this,

[screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbG9x.png)

now when I run this code which is invoked when I press ctrl+F
and if I enter "alfozen" into the input dialog,
then it selects 1st, 3rd item,5th and 7th, no matter what I search the index 0(1st item) is always shown selected,This is my first question at stackOverflow , please let me know if I should provide more information on the issue.Thanks a lot in advance

this is the code,

```
if ((ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F) && ((ke.getModifiers() & 
KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK) != 0))
{
 int i=0,j=0;

 lst.clearSelection();
 lst.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

 String s=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Name to search : ");
   if(s==null)return;

 String arg[]=new String[vct.size()];
 int arr[]=new int[vct.size()];

 for(people p : vct)
 {
  arg[i++]=p.toString();
 }

for(j=0,i=0;j<arg.length;j++)
{
 if(arg[j].contains(s))
 {
  arr[i++]=j;
 }
}
lst.setSelectedIndices(arr);
lst.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
}
```

Comment: You will likely need to create and post a valid [mcve] or [sscce](http://sscce.org) to get a decent answer. Please look at these links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be *because you told it to.*

After your loops, the first `i` elements of arr contain the indices that match. What do the rest contain? Well, you never assigned anything to them, so they hold the default `int` value 0.

So if you have 5 elements, and the second, third and fifth elements match, then `ar` contains 1, 2, 4, 0, 0.

So when you call `lst.setSelectedIndices(arr);`, elements 1, 2, 4, 0 and 0 are selected.

Comment: @ShubhamSaraswat `This is my first question at stackOverflow` - don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: @camickr Done! Thanks buddy!